# arraylist's add function not working for any class type i pass to it

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist

i am facing some issues in android/java programming. I want to declare an arraylist that can contain any class type.  my array list variable looks like this.
private ArrayList transactionList;

i have various classes such as Income class, Debit class, Creditcard class, Events class.  these classes have their own get and set methods.
im reading data from a database and calling my set methods and then adding that class object to my arraylist.  for example

```
 Cursor data = connectionDB.getListContents(selectQuery);
        Income income;
        transactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
        transactionList.clear();

        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            income = new Income();

            income.setIncomeAmount(data.getString(0));
            income.setFrequency(data.getString(1));
            income.setDatePaid(data.getString(2));
            income.setCategory(data.getString(3));
            income.setDepositTo(data.getString(4));
            income.setDescription(data.getString(5));
            income.setRecordSetId(data.getString(6));
            income.setRowid(data.getString(7));
            income.setStatus(data.getString(8));

            income.setColumnValues(
                    data.getColumnName(0)
                    , data.getColumnName(1)
                    , data.getColumnName(2)
                    , data.getColumnName(3)
                    , data.getColumnName(4)
                    , data.getColumnName(5)
                    , data.getColumnName(6)
                    , data.getColumnName(7)
                    , data.getColumnName(8)
            );



            transactionList.add(income);
        }
```

as you can see above, i am creating a new arraylist of Income

```
 transactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
```

but android studio is giving error when adding income to the arraylist such as
transactionList.add(income); 
"add (capture ) in arrayList cannot be applied to (com.finsec.Income)"

i searched other postings but couldnt find the answer i am looking for.
i would like to accomplish two things
1. declare arraylist of any class type and add to the arraylist. for example

```
 Income income = new Income();
   transactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
   transactionList.add(income);

   Debit debit= new Debit();
   transactionList = new ArrayList<Debit>();
   transactionList.add(debit);

   Events events= new Events();
   transactionList = new ArrayList<Events>();
   transactionList.add(events);
```

2. i want to pass the array list to a function
   print_arraylist( transactionList)

   i am not sure how to declare the parameter in the function
   i assume is public void transactionList(ArrayList list)
   and inside the function use instanceOf.  not sure

can someone help and let me know how to implement and arraylist of any class and be able to add to the arraylist and pass that arralist to a function?  thanks in advance

Comment: This could use a java tag.

Comment: can u post the complete class

Answer (score 0):

You should define ArrayList variable like this:

```
ArrayList<Income> a = new ArrayList<Income>();
ArrayList<debit> b = new ArrayList<debit>();
```

If you want to pass generic arraylist to a function, could do like this:

```
public void yourFun(ArrayList<?> arrayList, Class<Income> type) {
    for (Object o : arrayList) {
        if (o != null && o.getClass() == type) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
        ArrayList<Income> transactionList = new ArrayList<Income>();
        Income obj = new Income();
        transactionList.add(obj);
        yourFun(transactionList, Income.class);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i would like to know how would you cast the arraylist inside the function. for example,                           `code` public void yourFun(ArrayList<?> arrayList, Class<Income> type) {
    ArrayList<Income> arrayList2 = new arrayList2<>();                                           for (Object o : arrayList) {
        if (o != null && o.getClass() == type) {
            arrayList2=(ArrayList<Income>) arrayList
        }
    }
}

Comment: you are welcome, could you upvote or accept my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code looks correct.  If you get  "add (capture ) in arrayList cannot be applied to (com.finsec.Income)"  then it looks like you're leaving out important pieces of code, such as something that declares a variable called 'capture'.  I can run your code in Android Studio, there's no compile-time error or run-time error.

2.

```
void print_transactions(ArrayList transactionList)
{
    for (Object obj : transactionList) {
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

You can override 'public String toString() ...' in each of your classes to display it exactly as you want it to be displayed.  If you don't want to use 'toString()' for any reason then you'll need to define a base class or interface that all these classes use, and that interface will define a 'transactionToString()' method, and all the classes would need to implement it.